# differentiate equations using multiple rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently learning how to differentiate equations using multiple rules.

I have the following problem

[image]

First, I tried to solve the problem without simplify the equation, here is my solution, which I checked against the answer provided and it is correct

[image]

Next, I tried to simplify the equation first before trying to find its derivative. But I got a different solution (which I think is wrong, but I have checked my logics multiple times and every step seem to be make sense, to me at least)

[image]

Could someone please point out where I got it wrong?

Comment: They really are the same. Simplify the first expression further. For example, powers of cosine at the top and bottom can be cancelled, as can constants.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thanks for the tip. lol how silly of me. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You are welcome! Note that getting the same answer in two ways, and then verifying they are the same is a great exercise, so I upvote in appreciation of your effort.